# first 3 digits of a string

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to know the first 3 digits of a string?
I have written a function for the same. It is working as expected, but I will like to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
mysql> select areacode_fun('233434535');
+---------------------------+
| areacode_fun('233434535') |
+---------------------------+
| 233                       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select areacode_fun('2 33434535');
+----------------------------+
| areacode_fun('2 33434535') |
+----------------------------+
| 233                        |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select areacode_fun('2a33434535');
+----------------------------+
| areacode_fun('2a33434535') |
+----------------------------+
| 233                        |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select areacode_fun('(2a3)3434535');
+------------------------------+
| areacode_fun('(2a3)3434535') |
+------------------------------+
| 233                          |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why not post your code as well?

Comment: This is the kind of input validation you should be doing before you get to the database

Comment: With custom logic like yours, I guess your function is doing the right thing and is fine. If you are looking to get a solution in one single sql query, then it might not help. If you post your function, then people can help optimize that, at least.

Comment: *better way* compared to what? you need to post the `areacode_fun` code for us to suggest alternate/other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud, how about using [regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)?

```
SELECT '2a33434535' REGEXP '^[\+\-]?\d*\.?[Ee]?[\+\-]?\d*$';
```

Comment: and how it helps? result is zero, but expected 233